# Enter-PSSession, try with multiple credentials

Tags: powershell, credentials

I need to create a script that requires multiple credentials for establishing the connection to the computers.

I have tried to achieve this with a "try catch" and "if else", but the script looks pretty ugly and is not scalable if i need to insert more credentials.

There is a better way to achive the same results?

```
#credentiasl for non domain conputers and domain joined
$credential01 = Get-Credential domain 1\administrador
$credentiall02 = Get-Credential domain 2\administrador
$credentiall03 = Get-Credential workgroup\administrador

$error.clear()
#try to establish a remote sesion to the pc with the credentials01
try { etsn -ComputerName sldb04 -Credential $credential01 }

#if there is an error try to establish a remote sesion to the pc with the credentials02
catch 
{
    etsn -ComputerName sldb04 -Credential $credential02 

    #if the second credential is also wrong try the third
    If ($? -eq $false )
    {
        etsn -ComputerName sldb04 -Credential $credential03
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a best practice, don't attempt to guess the right account. This creates noise in the security logs and might lead into unexpected account lockouts.

Record the proper credentials for each environment and use it. You could store the credential mappings in a hash table like so,

```
# Add computer names and respective admin accounts into a hash table
$ht =  @{"computer01"="domain1\admin";"computer02"="domain2\admin";"computer03"="group\admin" }

# What's the account for computer01?
$ht["computer01"]
domain1\admin

# Print all computers and admin account names
$ht.GetEnumerator() | % { $("Logon to {0} as {1}" -f $_.name, $_.value) }
Logon to computer01 as domain1\admin
Logon to computer03 as group\admin
Logon to computer02 as domain2\admin
```

This can easily be extended by creating another a hashtable that stores credentials. Like so,

```
# Create empty hashable
$creds = @{}
# Iterate computer/account hashtable and prompt for admin passwords
$ht.GetEnumerator() | % { 
$c= get-credential $_.value
# Add only accounts that don't yet exist on the hashtable
if(-not $creds.Contains($_.value)) {
    $creds.Add($_.value, $c) }
}
# What's the account for domain1\admin?
$creds["domain1\admin"]
UserName                          Password
--------                          --------
domain1\admin System.Security.SecureString
```